# A Different Activity is Called in Landscape Mode Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have been having some trouble while trying to handle my Activities.  I am currently using 2 dialog activities to handle login and signup.

My main activity calls the login activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The login activity calls the signup activity like so.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

I have 2 activity_signup.xml files in layout and layout-land directories. For some reason, when I am in the signup activity and I rotate my screen, LoginActivity is called on top of the SignupActivity.

Here is my Manifest.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>


</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

## SOLUTION

So I have accidentally resolved the issue... When the orientation changed, the MainActivity saw a user was logged in and launched a new LoginActivity. Despite the SignupActivity being in the foreground. I can only assume it has to do with the fact that the LoginActivity and SignupActivity are dialog activity's.

Here is code for the MainActivity I used to check if the screen was rotated.

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //Check if user is logged in, launch LoginActivity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: It shouldnt happen it is happening because either that activity is being destroyed or you are calling some code which launces that activity onOrientationChange. Mind you by default when ever you rotate a screen onCreate is called.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.testnumber.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

This code will prevent from rotating the screen.You have to add this code in both the activity.

Comment: why prevent rotating screen??the question clearly states that there are two different layouts for 2 different modes.

Answer (score 0):

try add this to your SingupActivity

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

It allow only one iteration of activity